# Resize an image, from Django model form before uploading it to amazon s3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-forms, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize an image, before uploading it to S3 bucket, using PIL.
The model form is working perfectly well, except that the image resize does not happen.

Following is my models:

```
class ImageDetail(models.Model):

    def upload_image(self, filename):
        return u'obj/{name}.{ext}'.format(            
            name = uuid.uuid4().hex,
            ext  = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].strip('.')
        )
    flag = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    view = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Enter a small/suitable title")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_image, 
                          help_text="Please ensure, image size is less than 1 MB")
```

Views File, looks like this:

```
form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if form.is_valid() and request.POST:
    form_instance = form.save(commit=False)
    img = form_instance.image
    # process the image now
    if img.width > 300 or img.height > 200:
        IMG_TYPE = os.path.splitext(img.name)[1].strip('.').lower()
        if IMG_TYPE == 'jpeg':
            PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'jpeg'
        elif IMG_TYPE == 'jpg':
            PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'jpeg'
        elif IMG_TYPE == 'png':
            PIL_TYPE = 'png'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'png'
        elif IMG_TYPE == 'gif':
            PIL_TYPE = 'gif'
            FILE_EXTENSION = 'gif'
        else:
            print 'Not a valid format'
            return
        im = Image.open(StringIO(img.read()))
        im.thumbnail((300, 180), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        #Save the image
        temp_handle = StringIO()
        im.save(temp_handle, PIL_TYPE)
        s3 = S3Custom()
        if not form_instance.image:
            return self.success(self.request, form, None, errors = 'Error while uploading the image')
        form_instance.save()
```

The S3 custom function is defined as follows:

```
class S3Custom(object):
    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    b = Bucket(conn, settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
    k = Key(b)
    def upload_file(self, ruta, prefix):
        try:           
            self.k.key = '%s/%s' % (prefix, os.path.split(ruta)[-1])
            self.k.set_contents_from_filename(ruta)
            self.k.make_public()
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        return '%s%s' % (settings.S3_URL, self.k.key)
```

I have installed `django-storage`. The trouble is, the image gets uploaded pretty well, but is not resized properly. What am I missing? Am I going wrong with

```
im.save(temp_handle, PIL_TYPE)
s3 = S3Custom()
form_instance.save()
```

in the views file?
Please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first things first: you almost certainly don't want to resize synchronously - instead, kick off a Celery task (or similar) to perform the resizing asynchronously after you've saved the original.

That aside, you never do anything with the `s3` object - `s3.upload_file` won't do much if it's never called...

(I also recommend using some kind of static analyser that will warn you about unused variables!)

Comment: thanks for your answer, the trouble i am unable to figure out is how is then the image gettting uploaded to the AWS machine.

Comment: Suspect you're doing something else with `django-storages`, but need to see more code (e.g. `ImageUploadForm`...)